# Make file - Compile and place reference into system folder

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile

I'm developing a library in C++ and compiling the library using GCC.

I'm looking for examples, or, tutorials in creating a make file. The idea will be this:

1. The user downloads the source of the library.
2. In command-prompt, executes the "make" file which:

   2.1 Compiles all of the class implementation, outputting to the library

   2.2 Places all of the references (classes) into the system folder.

2.2 will enable:

```
#include <audiolib/class.h>
```

instead of:

```
#include "audiolib/class.h"
```

I'm new to make files, so, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This may be a silly question, but did you try Google?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Hey, yes, I did try google but had no such luck. Especially with "b" in the points

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is often better to use a build system to generate your makefiles for you, rather than writing the scripts yourself. They aim to produce portable build scripts with only a little configuration on your end. The resulting scripts will often check the platform's capabilities and give you some way to vary the build depending on available features and functionality.

If you use the [GNU build system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_build_system) to generate your build scripts for you, you'll end up with the typical build process:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

The `make install` command is the one that will copy the build output to the correct directories, such as copying library headers to `/usr/include`, allowing the header to be found by your compiler.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Am I able to set the location of the library? I was looking here: [makefile](https://github.com/liyanghua/A-Simple-implementation-of-Hidden-Markov-Models/blob/master/Makefile) and I know it's boost BUT can I still set the library location like this example?

Answer (score 3):

How `#include <...>` and `#include "..."` work is nothing to do with Make, it's a behaviour of GCC.  Take a look at e.g. [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Include-Syntax.html) from the GCC documentation.